Why the unit of quantum information for anyons systems should be the qubit?
I'm starting to learn more about anyons systems. I took a read on this article which is an introduction to topological quantum computing, and also took a look in other places like forums and some other articles. What is normally shown is that some anyons models can (with R and F operations) be dense in U(2) by braiding, like Fibonacci anyons, and some not, like Ising anyons which implement the Clifford group by braiding.
My question is: Why the unit of information for anyons systems is always considered a two-level system? Why can't we be concerned if the braiding operations for some anyon system is dense in U(3) to form universal gates for qutrits? Is there something of the nature of anyons that make the unit of information of those systems intrinsic binary?

A classic source of anyon theories is the family $SU(2)_{k}$ where $k\geq1$. Such a theory has particle types $\{j/2\}_{j=0}^{k}$ and fusion rules
\begin{equation} j_{1}\times j_{2} = \sum_{j=|j_1 - j_2|}^{\min\{j_{1}+j_{2},k-j_{1}-j_{2}\}} j \end{equation}
where the sum increases in increments of $1$.
As you've noted, universality is an important property of an anyon theory when we want to build a quantum computer by braiding anyons. A theorem of [1] shows that $SU(2)_{k}$ is universal for the particle $1/2$  when $k\geq3$ and $k\neq4$. The case $k=1$ is an abelian theory with two particles (where the nontrivial particle is called a semion), and $k=2$ is closely related to the Ising theories, which as you've said, are not universal. Then, the smallest of these theories which is universal is $k=3$, which is a product theory $\mathrm{Fib} \times SU(2)_{1}$ (where $\mathrm{Fib}$ denotes a Fibonacci theory). A $k=3$ theory contains a second nonabelian anyon which is also universal for computing; namely, the $1$-particle known as a Fibonacci anyon. Note that a triple of $1$-particles (with total charge $1$) for $k=3$ encodes a qubit. Similarly, a triple of $1/2$ particles for $k=2$ encodes a qubit, and necessarily has total charge $1/2$.
To summarise a few reasons as to why textbook examples might focus on qubits:

A universal computational model based on qubits allows us to import and apply many things that we have learned from the study of quantum circuit models, which traditionally have qubits attached to each rail/wire.

The lowest 'rank' (i.e. having the smallest number of particles) anyon theories which are nonabelian are Fibonacci (rank 2) and Ising (rank 3). Each of these contain a single nonabelian anyon. The fusion rules associated to said anyon mean that their fusion states will encode qubits. So, perhaps unsurprisingly, the 'smallest' anyon theories naturally give rise to the smallest units of quantum information, which are qubits. When one first learns about anyon theories, naturally, one will encounter the smallest and most 'simple' anyon theories. Moreover, theories of smaller rank appear to be likelier to find a platform for physical realisation, and are hence of more practical relevance.


Indeed, there are examples of higher rank theories where, for instance, you could have a system of qutrits. E.g. a triple of $\beta$-anyons with overall charge $\beta$ encodes a qutrit, where $\beta^{2}=1+\alpha+\beta$, $\alpha\beta=\alpha+\beta$, and $\alpha^{2}=1+\beta$. This anyon generates a prime modular theory of rank $3$ (see 5.3.6 in [2]).
[1] Freedman, M., Larsen, M. and Wang, Z. (2002). "The Two-Eigenvalue Problem and Density of Jones Representation of Braid Groups". Communications in Mathematical Physics, 228.
[2] Rowell, E.C., Stong, R. and Wang, Z. (2009)."On Classification of Modular Tensor Categories". Communications in Mathematical Physics, 292(2).
